# Why do i get C as output for the following code snippet

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
float x=0.7;
clrscr();
if(x<0.7)
{
printf("c");
}
else
{
printf("c++");
}
getch(); 
}
```

output: C

if 0.7 is replaced with some more values like 1.7,0.8 in both places output is C++.
Why is this happening!

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth How did you find that?

Comment: @2501 https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=float%20double%20comparison%20site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: I wish SO would have better search. The same phrase finds nothing.